# How to align images and unordered list

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a website with an image horizontally aligned with a navigation bar, but I cant figure out how. I've tried floating, but all it does is put the picture **on top** of the navigation bar. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Thanks!

**CSS and HTML-**

```css
#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 550px;
  height: 250px;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: #E66916;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  width: 800px;
  height: 250px;
}
a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Baumans;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
  color: #FFDAC2;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 50px;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My Physical Fitness Tracker</title>

  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <img id="logo" src="file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Owner/Desktop/Commander%20%20Outpost/IMAGES/MPFT.png" alt="Personal Physical Fitness Tracker" />

    <div id="navbar">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">about</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">myfitness</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">confidencebooster</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could add `display: inline-block;` to `#logo` and remove the float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display:inline-block`to `#logo` and `#navbar`

**CSS**

```
#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 550px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: #E66916;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  width: 800px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hp20wcrd/34/)**

Note: You need to horizontal expand the browser because your image and menu have a size...you must expect that!

If you want to force it you must set `white-space:nowrap` on `header`

**CSS**

```
header{
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1f050smo/2/)**

Comment: Thanks Luis! You just made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle for context http://jsfiddle.net/1f050smo/1/

You can set `#logo` and `#navbar` to `display: inline-block;`

You also need to set `vertical-align: top` to both the `#logo` and `#navbar` elements as the default value is baseline, which would place `#navbar` toward the bottom of `#logo`.

```
#logo,
#navbar {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and remove the float from `#logo`

```
#logo {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
}
```